# Finding the power series solution of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am trying to find the power series solution for $y'' - 2xy' - 3y = 0$. I have done all the work and gotten the first 4 terms for the recurrence relation. However, I am having a hard time finding the pattern to make the solution into a series.

What I got was. $$y = a[1 + \frac32x^2 + \frac{21}{24}x^4 + \frac{231}{720}x^6 +...] + b[x + \frac56x^3 + \frac{45}{120}x^5 +...].$$

I know that we have $x^{2n}$ for the first series and $x^{2n+1}$ for the second along with the denominators being $(2n)!$ and $(2n+1)!$ respectively however I am having trouble determining the rest.

I know the numerator should have $(4n - 1)(4n - 5)(4n - 9)(...)$ repeated for the first series. Is there any way to simplify this into a factorial or something?

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine the power series representation
$$
 y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$$
of the solution, you plug the power series in the differential equation. For instance, for the first derivative you have
$$
 y'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n x^{n-1}.
$$
Then you collect terms and group by powers of $x^n$. Once your are there, ask yourself: when does a power series vanish? When you have figured out the answer, it is easy to state the formula for the coefficients $a_n$.